# After Stop-Process, task still shows on Get-Process

Tags: powershell

I run this script to kill the duplicate process. When I `Get-Process` again after `Stop-Process`, the process ID is still show out on `Get-Process`.
Even if I try `Wait-Process -Id $LPID`, `(Stop-Process -Id $LPID -Force).WaitForExit()`, I still get an incorrect count.

But when I put a delay on line 10 (`Start-Sleep`), then it shows the correct count.

May I know why?
Is it because of multi-threading?
Here I attach the result also.

[image: Screenshot]

First part without `Start-Sleep`, second part with `Start-Sleep`.

Script:

```
Get-Process -Name fdm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
$fdmcount = (Get-Process -Name fdm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count
if ( $fdmcount -gt 1 ) {
    do {
        $LFDM = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name = 'fdm.exe'" |
                select -Last 1)
        $LPID = $LFDM.handle
        echo "kill $LPID"
        Stop-Process -Id $LPID -Force
        #Start-Sleep 1
        Get-Process -Name fdm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $fdmcount = (Get-Process -Name fdm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Count
    } while ($fdmcount -gt 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `Get-Process` returns a process instance doesn't mean that that process is still running - the OS will keep the process entry around briefly after the process has exited, which explains why it might take a few seconds for your script to reflect that.

The solution is fairly simple - just filter on whether the process has exited or not:

```
# only returns still-running processes 
Get-Process -Name fdm -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Where { -not $_.HasExited }
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be not to mix [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi).  I removed a lot of extra logic from your code:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

Get-Process -Name fdm
while ((Get-Process -Name fdm).Count -gt 1) {
    $lfdm = Get-Process -Name fdm | Select-Object -Last 1
    "kill $($lfdm.Id)"
    $lfdm | Stop-Process -Force

    Get-Process -Name fdm
}
```

If you do want to stick to [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi) instead:

```
$gcimParams = @{
    ClassName = 'Win32_Process'
    Filter    = 'Name="fdm.exe"'
}
Get-CimInstance @gcimParams
while ((Get-CimInstance @gcimParams).Count -gt 1) {
    $lfdm = Get-CimInstance @gcimParams | Select-Object -Last 1
    "kill $(lfdm.Handle)"
    $lfdm | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Terminate -Arguments @{Reason = 0}

    Get-CimInstance @gcimParams
}
```